# Write Query With 3 Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `CustomerPurchases` Table which stores data of each customer's purchases.

I want to retrieve customers who have had at least 2 purchases in less than 4 days apart, with at least 100000 unit amount.

In Oracle, maybe we can handle the condition of the query with below query, but i want a query to write in sql server:

```
select * from 
(Select distinct  CustomerId,
Sum(PurchaseAmount) over (Partition By CustomerId Order By PrchaseDate  Range Between Interval  4 Day Preceding and Current Row ) as PurchaseAmount,
Count(*) over (Partition By CustomerId Order By PrchaseDate  Range Between Interval  4 Day Preceding and Current Row ) as PurchaseCount
From Customer Purchases) a
Where PurchaseAmount>=100000 and PuchaseCount>=2
```

For example, considering the table below it should only show CustomerId 3 and 4:

| Id | CustomerId | Purchasedate | PurchaseAmount | PurchaseTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-10-01 | 500000 | 10:10:10 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021_11_01 | 100000 | 10:10:10 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022_03_05 | 100 | 10:10:10 |
| 4 | 3 | 2022_03_07 | 100000 | 10:10:10 |
| 5 | 2 | 2022_03_07 | 100000 | 10:10:10 |
| 6 | 4 | 2022_03_07 | 100 | 10:10:10 |
| 7 | 4 | 2022_03_07 | 400000 | 11:10:10 |

Comment: While I agree that some things are easy in Oracle and difficult in SQL Server, I don't understand what you are refering to here. You mention a window function with a range, but both DBMS feature window functions. What exactly do you think is it that you can do in Oracle, but not in SQL Server here? Can you please show the Oracle query that would do the task? I am pretty sure it will be easy to convert this to SQL Server.

Comment: Why are date and time separated columns by the way? Is one of them nullable to indicate "complete day" or "everyday" or the like? Or what else is the idea behind this? Must we consider the time when evaluating whether two purchases are no more than four days apart?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i add the oracle query but i'm not sure about it. i dont presist to write this query with window function, i just want to write the query in the most simple way. i will be appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: Doesn't your table have something to identify a row? It looks like you can put two identical rows in the table. Is this so? Or is there a unique constraint on customerid + puchasedate + puchasetime? (Your customer 4 examples suggest it is not.) Or is there a unique ID you are not showing us?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i add time just to show that  if we have a customer that had 2 purchase in one day, we should consider it....i dont want to use time in query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i add identity row

Comment: Thank you. The Oracle query is invalid though.  `Range Between Interval  4 Day Preceding ...` is not a window clause. `Range Between  4 Preceding ...` is, but the same applies to SQL Server. So, no, this is not easy to do in Oracle either it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work: Per purchase get all other purchases in the four-days range for the same customer. Count these purchases and add up the purchase amount and only keep purchases matching your criteria. Then select distinct customers from the matching purchases.

```
select distinct p1.customerid
from customer_purchases p1
join customer_purchases p2 
  on  p2.id <> p1.id
  and p2.customerid = p1.customerid
  and p2.prchasedate >= p1.prchasedate
  and p2.prchasedate < date_add(day, 4, p1.prchasedate)
group by p1.customerid, p1.id
having count(*) >= 2 and sum(purchaseamount) >= 100000;
```